# uilongpressgesturerecognizer fire only once

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to add a gesture that will only fire if a person has been pressing for a second or so. Not a tap but a long press. If I use uilongpressgesturerecognizer it keeps firing until I release my finger. How can I get around this.

Comment: What state of the gesture are you using to see this? If you switch on `gestureRecognizer.state` and only look for the `.Ended` state, then it will only occur once per long press (at the end of the long press).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set `minimumPressDuration` when you create and add gesture as below:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
```

Write your code in `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` state as below:

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)Gesture{

    if (Gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {


       //Do any thing after long press ended,which will be 1.0 second as set above


    }
    else if (Gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){



    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

Declare a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`:

```
let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gestureAction(gesture:)))
```

Set its `.minimumPressDuration` to `1.0` or any interval you want.

Set the recognizers `.delegate` to your ViewController and add it to your view using `.addGestureRecognizer()`.

Use the following function to handle the gesture:

```
@objc func gestureAction(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if let longPress = gesture as? UILongPressGestureRecognizer {
        if longPress.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {

        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set value of `minimumPressDuration` property of `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.